# How can I solve this error when I try to upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, apt-get

I have a virtual machine in a Google Compute Engine which is running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64)

I want to make a periodic upgrade (I DON'T want to upgrade it to 16.04!) I just want to maintain it updated. Since some days, it's retrieving an error and I can't update it properly.

Each time I try to upgrade it, it says:

> 17 not fully installed or removed.

Sometimes I've tried an autoclean or an autoremove and the machine crashed forever, so I had to resucite it from snapshots. Any help will be appreciated.

This is the complete output I get when I make an `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-51
  linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-3.19.0-73-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-74-generic linux-image-3.19.0-75-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-77-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-73-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-74-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-75-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-77-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 16 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
17 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,433 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 230239 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-75-generic (3.19.0-75.83~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-75-generic /                                                                  boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-75-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-75-generic /b                                                                  oot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-75-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-75-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-75-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-75-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.19.0-75-generic (3.19.0-75.83~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-75-generic /boo                                                                  t/vmlinuz-3.19.0-75-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-75-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-75-generic /boot                                                                  /vmlinuz-3.19.0-75-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-78-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-77-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic
done
The link /initrd.img is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
The link /initrd.img.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img.old
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-77-generic (3.19.0-77.85~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-77-generic /                                                                  boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-77-generic /b                                                                  oot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-77-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-77-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-77-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-77-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.19.0-77-generic (3.19.0-77.85~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-77-generic /boo                                                                  t/vmlinuz-3.19.0-77-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-77-generic /boot                                                                  /vmlinuz-3.19.0-77-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-78-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic
done
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-51-generic /b                                                                  oot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-51-generic /bo                                                                  ot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-51-generic /boot                                                                  /vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/                                                                  vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-78-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic
done
The link /vmlinuz.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link vmlinuz.old
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic (4.4.0-45.66~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-45 (4.4.0-45.66~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-51 (4.4.0-51.72~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-73-generic (3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-73-generic /                                                                  boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-73-generic /b                                                                  oot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-73-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-ima                                                                  ge-3.19.0-73-generic (3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-73-generic /boo                                                                  t/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-73-generic /boot                                                                  /vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-78-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic
done
Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-74-generic (3.19.0-74.82~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-74-generic /                                                                  boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-74-generic /b                                                                  oot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-74-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-ima                                                                  ge-3.19.0-74-generic (3.19.0-74.82~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-74-generic /boo                                                                  t/vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-74-generic /boot                                                                  /vmlinuz-3.19.0-74-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-78-generic
done
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic (4.4.0-45.66~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-45-generic /b                                                                  oot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-45-generic /bo                                                                  ot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-ima                                                                  ge-4.4.0-45-generic (4.4.0-45.66~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-45-generic /boot                                                                  /vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-45-generic /boot/                                                                  vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-78-generic
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-75-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-77-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-73-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-74-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You should post this on AskUbuntu or SuperUser instead.

Comment: You might want to check that you have [enough swap space](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219309/xz-cannot-allocate-memory). Additionally make sure to [run apt-get update before apt-get upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade).